# Build failed when removing migrations in asp.net razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-scaffolding

## **I want to remove some unnecessary fields added in my class model without starting the project from scratch**

**Context:**

- I am creating a website using **RazorPages**.
- I used the code-first approach and started by creating **classes of my model**.
- I added ***new scaffolded item*** for each table to create the pages
- Then Ran `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`
- When I ran the app it went well but I saw that I added some fields that I want removed: e.g.,

```
public class Animal 
{
   [Key]
   public int id {get; set;}

   public string? surname {get; set;} // I WANT THIS ONE REMOVED
}
```

**What I did:**

1. Went to the code and removed that line
2. Opened **Package Manager Console** and ran `Update-Database` - **IT FAILED**
3. Figured I need to scrap the Migration and run `Remove-Migration` - Which also **failed**.

**The Error** insists that the field I had deleted is missing, which is my intention.

**ErrorMessage**

```
Error   CS1061  'X' does not contain a definition for 'X_Field_1' and no accessible extension method 'X_Field_1' accepting a first argument of type 'X' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**Goal:** I would like to remove just the field and make the changes to my database then run my web pages without scrapping my folders - scaffolding takes too long on my pc!

Comment: Did step 2 fail with an error? Or did it just not do what you want? Generally removing stuff from model (like that field) is ok, but it requires a new migration (add migration) for changes to be reflected in db as well

Comment: @arynaq, yes it was the same error. I figured I don't need to add a new migration again and just update the existing one? but let me try it

Comment: @arynaq adding a new migration failed as well

Comment: Delete the migration folder and database, then `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` again.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have 3 options here.

**Option 1: Start Again**

If it's really early in your development cycle (And from the look of this code it is) Simply Delete your DB delete all your migrations and snapshot and start again with a new initial migration.
`dotnet ef add-migration initial`, `dotnet ef database update`

**Options 2: Remove And Recreate**

1. Roll back database to previous state `dotnet ef database update <previousmigrationname>`
2. Remove the migration. `dotnet ef migration remove`
3. Add the new migration `dotnet ef migration add <newmigrationname>`

**Option 3: Plough Ahead**

Instead of rolling back the migration, once you've changed the model simply add a new migration to remove the columns you don't want and update the database.

Comment: Thank You. It looks like I can only have 1 option, which is the first and the one I was trying to avoid. The other two I have tried as well and they failed.